# I am new to bootstrap and am trying to build a navigation bar but when I put the proper code in, the nav bar doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to bootstrap and am trying to build a navigation bar but when I put the proper code in, the nav bar doesn't appear. I am using bootstrap 4 which I'm not sure if I am using the wrong code for the version I am using. Here is my code...

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
         <title>Company Website</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <!--Create navbar-->
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src=""></a>
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
    
        <!--Create header-->
    
        <!--Create icons with text-->
    
        <!--create contact button-->
    
        <!--Create footer-->
    
    
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That looks more like BS3 code than BS4

Comment: Put some content into navbar. At least image link or "Hello world"  And check if your code is for bootstrap4.

Answer (score 0):

The `nav` element is there, but Bootstrap 4 doesn't include `navbar-inverse` class. That's why you can't see it.

You can use [`navbar-dark` and `bg-dark`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#color-schemes) classes instead, which gives you the desired effect that I think you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <title>Company Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```